# PHP, fputcsv, Want to write each array as a column not a row

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fputcsv

Simple Example:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(10,20,30,40);
$c = array(100,200,300,400);
```

If I execute the following:

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.csv','w');
fputcsv($fp,$a);
fputcsv($fp,$b);
fputcsv($fp,$c);
fclose($fp);
```

I get a file that looks like this:

```
1,2,3,4
10,20,30,40
100,200,300,400
```

As I would expect. However what I want is:

```
1,10,100
2,20,200
3,30,300
4,40,400
```

Is this possible without just looping and writing each index from each array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using loops? It is so easy.

```
$fp = fopen('somefile.csv','w');
for ($i = 0 ; $i < 4 ; $i++){
  fputcsv($fp, array($a[$i], $b[$i], $c[$i])) ;
}
fclose($fp) ;
```

Comment: I wonder how efficient it would be if say, there were 5 arrays with 100,000 elements? Guess i'll have to test and find out. Any thoughts?

Comment: @kpurdon Upgraded the code for better performance, as you dont have to call function in loop.

Comment: @kpurdon In fact, I find it very efficient, because using `array_*` functions is generally slower, than looping arrays and performing simple actions.

Comment: I'm not sure the "performance" one works. For me it just writes "Array,Array..." as strings to the CSV file. Adding a foreach() and looping through each sub-array and writing, solves. So is it faster to compile a large array then write in a foreach loop. Or just write from the first loop.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about 2d array, it doesnt work this way. I just misunderstood the function. But anyways, thanks for the task.

Comment: fputcsv instead of fputscv =/